# ayuda con un crud

Tags: php, mvc

mi error es este: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\wamp\www\fomulario persona1\fomulario persona1\Modelo\modelopersona.php on line 55

esta es mi vista
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el modelo

```
function editarpersona()
{
    $sql = "UPDATE persona SET nombre=?, apellido=?, fecha_ingre=?,
    edad=?";
    $obj = $this->conex->prepare($sql);
    $obj->bindValue(2,$_POST['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(3,$_POST['apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(4,$_POST['fecha_ingre'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(5,$_POST['edad'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->execute();
}
```

mi controlador
    
require_once("../Modelo/modelopersona.php");

```
$obj = new persona();
if (isset($_POST['cedula']))
{
    $value = $obj->mostrarpersona();
}

if (isset($_POST['enviar']) and $_POST['enviar']=='si')
{
    $value = $obj->editarpersona();
    var_dump($obj);
}
require_once("../Vista/vistaeditar.php");
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

El error tiene que ver con la cantidad de parámetros que estás usando al hacer los `bindValue()`.

Tu sql tiene 4 parámetros identificados con "?", que deberían ir numerados del 1 al 4, pero en los bindValues usas los identificadores 2 al 5 con lo que dejas una "?" sin sustituir, y por eso el error del parámetro faltante.

Corregido, tu código sería:

```
function editarpersona() {
    $sql = "UPDATE persona SET nombre = ?, apellido = ?, fecha_ingre = ?, edad = ?";
    $obj = $this->conex->prepare($sql);
    $obj->bindValue(1, $_POST['nombre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(2, $_POST['apellido'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(3, $_POST['fecha_ingre'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->bindValue(4, $_POST['edad'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $obj->execute(); 
}
```

Un caso parecido está documentado como el ejemplo #2 del [manual de PHP PDOStatement::bindvalue](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)